# How to I change this Excel macro (VBA) to run on any sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have an excel with data arranged in tables for several schools. Each school is on a separate worksheet. The following code (recorded macro) will produce a chart for the referenced sheet (`2002 - CJS`). How can I amend it to create the chart on any sheet?

```
Sub Gendergraph()
'
' Gendergraph Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='2002 - CJS'!$B$2"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
        "='2002 - CJS'!$D$3:$D$6,'2002 - CJS'!$D$10:$D$12"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "='2002 - CJS'!$E$2"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = _
        "='2002 - CJS'!$G$3:$G$6,'2002 - CJS'!$G$10:$G$12"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = _
        "='2002 - CJS'!$B$3:$B$6,'2002 - CJS'!$B$10:$B$12"
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are the data ranges for the chart the same on each sheet?

Comment: Hi Gareth - data range is the same for each worksheet. Tried deleting "'2002 - CJS'!" Think it might be to do with that and/or the "activechart' on the lines...?

Comment: Should the charts all be on one sheet or on the sheet with the data?

Comment: Must be such a noob - simply cannot get either of your suggestions to run! Opening VBA editor, insert module, pasting code. Macro not appearing in the list so I can't run it!

Comment: Add it to a standard module, not a worksheet or ThisWorkbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that all of the sheets in the workbook are wanting a chart generating, you can iterate through the sheets and add a chart like so:

```
Sub Gendergraph()
'
' Gendergraph Macro
'
    Dim ws as Worksheet

    For Each ws in Thisworkbook.Worksheets

        ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$2"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
            "='" & ws.Name & "'!$D$3:$D$6,'" & ws.Name & "'!$D$10:$D$12"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$2"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = _
            "='" & ws.Name & "'!$G$3:$G$6,'" & ws.Name & "'!$G$10:$G$12"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = _
            "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$3:$B$6,'" & ws.Name & "'!$B$10:$B$12"

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Gareth, got it working! This does indeed create a chart for each worksheet. However, it piles them on top of each other in one worksheet. Is it worth considering adjusting this code so it will put each chart in the correct sheet?

Comment: Sorry missed the `ActiveSheet` in the code which needs to be changed to `ws`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Line 10 (xlcolumnclustered line) error states: object variable or With block variable not set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start thinking of the generic process that's taking place - you're adding a chart to a worksheet, then setting the title and data of the chart.

Using ActiveSheet (or any Active* object) is not a great way to do this (or anything really, the Excel macro recorder writes some awful code...).

The approach I would use would be to pass a Worksheet into a Sub that adds the chart, i.e.

```
Sub Gendergraph(ws As Worksheet)

    With ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = ws.Range("B2")
            .Values = Union(ws.Range("D3:D6"), ws.Range("D10:D12"))
        End With

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = ws.Range("E2")
            .Values = Union(ws.Range("G3:G6"), ws.Range("G10:G12"))
            .XValues = Union(ws.Range("B3:B6"), ws.Range("B10:B12"))
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Now all you need is another routine that passes each worksheet into that procedure and all your sheets will have a chart added.

Comment: I have tried to get this to work - it won't run with the text in the parentheses, with "Dim ws As Worksheet" it has an error 91 on line 3 (with ws...)